# How does synchronization works on an Object using objectId or hashcode?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Can someone please explain how synchronization obtains lock on an Object?

I have a code in which I want to obtain a lock on the String value dynamically.

for e.g.

```
String a = "abc";
synchronization(a){
   //some logic
}
```

Now what I want is if from an api I receive value of a abc from one request and on the other request I receive value of a as abc while obtaining lock on the previous request, the new request should wait on the basis of value.

Can someone please help how it works/ how can I achieve this?

Comment: Synchronization is based on Object monitors. You should be using explicit locks.

Comment: That would be an overhead on the process, I don't want it either as there will be million of requests and I don't want to maintain any cache as well as neither a global variable to maintain the lock

Comment: These locks are not based on the values inside the objects. If you need a lock based on value, you should probably use some other locking mechanism, and yes, it will have to be global.

Comment: You can't guarantee that objects with the same value will be the same object - so you can't rely on this kind of synchronization. You need to use explicit locks based on the the specific values that you care about.

Comment: note the correct syntax is `synchronized(a) { .. }` , see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 3):

> Now what I want is if from an api I receive value of a abc from one request and on the other request I receive value of a as abc while obtaining lock on the previous request, the new request should wait on the basis of value.

To use `synchronized` for this, you'd need to ensure that the `"abc"` objects were the **same string object**, not just equivalent strings (for the same reason [you don't compare strings with `==`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)), by using `intern`.

```
synchronized (a.intern()) {
    // ...
}
```

`synchronized` requires the same object, not just equivalent ones.

---

That said, synchronizing on string objects to prevent two parts of your app handling equivalent requests at the same time seems (from the outside, without details) a bit odd, not least because it won't scale beyond a single JVM instance.

Comment: Re, "scalability", Also, depending on how many different strings the program could encounter in a single process lifetime, the `a.intern()` solution potentially could grow the interned string pool to an unmanageable size.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - It's not so much how many as how long they're held. Strings in the intern pool aren't exempt from GC if nothing but the pool has a reference to them.